# Recursive decimal to binary converter in C

Tags: c, recursion

I wrote a recursive function passing a string (I also tried passing a string pointer (char**)) to generate a binary string representation, and it works perfectly in xcode, however it doesn't work in HackerRank. Any ideas why this isn't working?

```
char* binaryRep( int n, char* binString ){
    if( n>1 ){
        snprintf(binString,25,"%s%d",binaryRep(n/2,binString),n%2);
        return binString;
    } else {
        snprintf(binString,25,"%d",n%2);
        return binString;
    }
}

int main(){
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);

    char* binString = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*25);
    binaryRep( n, binString );

    printf("%s\n",binString);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is HackerRank?

Comment: HackerRank has a sandbox with their compiler. Add some debug strings and debug it.

Comment: No idea why because we don't have access to HackerRank.

Comment: When copying occurs between overlapping objects in a region, its behavior is undefined.

Comment: And I definitely won't go with a recursive solution to this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because HackerRank is not accessible and it's impossible to verify that actual question was indeed what you specified here (there may be constraints/rules that you missed), and therefore whether the answer is relevant. There may also be issues in how HackerRank does I/O so not really reproducible.

Comment: From [this `printf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf): "The C standard and POSIX specify that the behavior of sprintf and its variants is undefined when an argument overlaps with the destination buffer." You use `binString` as both a source argument *and* a destination argument, that's *overlapping*.